# Is there any reference for labour finance?

Tags: reference-request, finance, corporate-finance

Is there any recent reference for labour finance, in which labour finance relating to financial statements? And what are the alternative name for "labour finance"?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "labour finance"?

Comment: This is a terminology I accidentally hear from a seminar, which relates to Business Ethics

Comment: @Curiosity if this is concept from business ethics then it is off topic on this site unless that was term that was just thrown around the seminar and typically it’s not used in ethics